# Using driver.switchTo() is automatically clearing the cookie (Selenium web driver-Java)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My scenario is, when I hit the URL the page should navigate to the authentication window and after enter the valid user ID and password, the main page gets displayed and upon clicking any link in the main page, a new window will open and displays the corresponding page without any authentication.

**Issue :** when I use the switchTo() in the code, clicking the link from the main page is opening a new window and again prompting me to enter the user ID and pass.

### If I remove that switchTo(), upon clicking it is taking me to the expected page wihout authentication.

```
**Code** import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
public class MKTEvent {
public WebDriver driver;
public String baseUrl;

public void testMKTEvent() throws IOException, BiffException, InterruptedException {

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
baseUrl = "<<URL>>";
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(baseUrl);
File f=new File("D:\\User ID.xls");
Workbook w=Workbook.getWorkbook(f);
Sheet s=w.getSheet(0);
for(int i=1;i<s.getRows();i++)
{
    String uname=s.getCell(0,i).getContents();
    String pass=s.getCell(1,i).getContents();
    driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).sendKeys(uname);
    driver.findElement(By.name("j_password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("j_password")).sendKeys(pass);
    driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();


   Thread.sleep(15000);

   driver.findElement(By.id("Dashboard")).click();


   String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
   System.out.println(parentWindow);
  for(String windowHandle  : driver.getWindowHandles()){
   if(!windowHandle.equals(parentWindow))
   {
   driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
   String nt = driver.findElement(By.id("createRequest")).getText();
   System.out.println(nt);
   driver.findElement(By.id("createRequest")).click();

}
}
}
}
}
```

---

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using DesiredCapabilities will solve your issue.

```
  DesiredCapabilities IECapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
  IECapabilities.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", false);
  IECapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
  IECapabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
  IECapabilities.setCapability("ie.ensureCleanSession", false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I add the capabilities. but still facing the same issue.